# Asynchronous SQS with Ruby aws-sdk

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk

I'm trying to use  asynchronous SQS as explained here: http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-sqs-long-polling-batching/ but not sure if current Ruby aws SDK supports it and much less how to do it with? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Shoryuken](https://github.com/phstc/shoryuken), it's a ruby client on top of the AWS SDK.